# How do I properly run my app when doing e2e tests?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, e2e-testing, cypress

**We have a frontend app that we serve and we want to do e2e tests on it on a CI server. What is the best approach to do that?**

The whole test should run on a non-gui CI, executable with a single command.

What would come to my mind is something like this:

`concurrently "npm run serve" "npx cypress run"`

But this seems to add a huge and uneccessary overhead. Plus I somehow have to make sure that the tests don't execute before the app is actually served.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Cypress continuous integration docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Boot-your-server), you can use a npm package called [wait-on](https://github.com/jeffbski/wait-on) to wait for your server before running Cypress:

```sh
npm run serve & # run this in the background
wait-on http://localhost:8000 && npm run cypress
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a definite solution, but just some thoughts. We are using a bash script which results in starting the tests with one command. In that bash script we have this:

```
    # environment variables
    export HOME=${PWD}

    yarn install
    ./node_modules/.bin/cypress install
    ./node_modules/.bin/cypress verify

    ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run ${SMOKETEST}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about automating all e2e workflows with [endly](https://github.com/viant/endly) 
e2e test runner.

Starting app and delegating testing to cypress may look like the following

@test.yaml

```
pipeline:
  test:
    multiAction: true
    startApp:
      async: true
      action: exec:run
      commands:
        - npm run serve
    runTest:
      async: true
      action: exec:run
      commands:
        - wait-on http://localhost:8000 && npm run cypress
```